# Changes made to the global variable inside a function is not available to another function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 scope functions and have declared one global scope variable.
I have made the changes for the global variable in one function but it is not reflected in the other function in angularjs .

The scenario is like I have a checkbox in table and have written a function where values will be pushed to the `$scope.selection=[];` if the checkbox is checked.

I have another delete button which is calling delete function and the delete operation will be performed with the value stored in the array.But I am getting the empty array instead of the modified one when I give `console.log()` inside the delete function. Kindly let me know your suggestions.

Code:

```
$scope.selectionlist = [];
$scope.selectitem = function(itemselected){ 
    if(itemselected.isChecked === true) {        
      $scope.selectionlist.push(itemselected.xyz); 
    } 
}
$scope.deletememo = function(){
    console.log("selection inside deletememo",$scope.selectionlist.length);      
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? Maybe a jsFiddle?

Comment: $scope.selectionlist = [];
$scope.selectitem = function(itemselected){         

if(itemselected.isChecked === true)
{
  $scope.selectionlist.push(itemselected.xyz);  
}
 }

  $scope.deletememo = function(){
    console.log("selection inside deletememo",$scope.selectionlist.length);
    
  }

Comment: code.. code.. code..

Answer (score 1):

Though @denny jonh has answered your question, but still if you don't understand you can refer my answer too

**JS**

```
var app=angular.module("tableApp",[]);
app.controller("tblCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.selectedItem=[];
  $scope.tableValues=[{
    "id":1,
    "name" : "dave",
    "country":"india",
    "designation":"software dev"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name" : "giri",
    "country":"USA",
    "designation":"QA"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name" : "dora",
    "country":"UK",
    "designation":"UI"
  }
  ]
  $scope.change=function(data){
    if(data.isChecked){
      $scope.selectedItem.push(data);
    }
    else{
      $scope.selectedItem.splice($scope.selectedItem.indexOf(data),1)
    }
  }
  $scope.displaySelectedRow=function(){
    if($scope.selectedItem==""){
      console.log("Select a row atleast")
    }
    else{
      console.log("The selected Row Value is: ",$scope.selectedItem);
    }
  }
})
```

Working [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fs9WTSOAAyFwIPgcJYNX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks .  what if my table is in partial view. I tried keeping my delete button inside the partial view page, its working. But if I keep the delete button in main page I am getting the same error. how to inform about the changes in the partial view to the main view. Its like I am calling the delete function from the main page and the table with checkbox is in the partial page.

Comment: First I am searching the db with a specified condition and then displaying the table  in partial view. So the list button is in the main page. when I try to put the delete button next to it I am not getting the output as expected.

Comment: I think it's not with the button problem, it is the problem of calling the delete function, try declaring the seletedItem variable array in global within partial view and create a function in main page access the global array variable within that function and assign it to delete button ng-click, I think it may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. I am having the delete button in my partial page and it is working fine :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Run code snippet to see the result.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mainCntrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.selectionlist = [];
  
  $scope.memo = [{'name': 'denny'},
                 {'name': 'john'},
                 {'name': 'joe'},
                 {'name': 'snowden'}
                 ];

  $scope.selectedItem = function(data){
    if(data.checkbox){
      $scope.selectionlist.push(data);
      console.log($scope.selectionlist);
      }
  else{
      var index = $scope.selectionlist.indexOf(data);
      $scope.selectionlist.splice(index, 1); 
      console.log($scope.selectionlist);
      }
    };

  $scope.deleteMemo = function(){
     console.log($scope.selectionlist);
   };
  
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCntrl">
    <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="x in memo">
      <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.checkbox" ng-  change="selectedItem(x)"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 <button ng-click="deleteMemo()">Delete</button>
</div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks . what if my table is in partial view. I tried keeping my delete button inside the partial view page, its working. But if I keep the delete button in main page I am getting the same error. how to inform about the changes in the partial view to the main view. Its like I am calling the delete function from the main page and the table with checkbox is in the partial page.